# Splitting column into two columns with different string counts in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I have a table ML, with column Klubs:

[image: table]

I want to split this column so I have two columns like this. New table name ML2 and column name Region.

First column can have 2 words if they are different from 2nd column word.

[image: desired output]

I am new to MySQL and searched all over stackoverflow and internet , but no luck.

How can split column Klubs from table ML as in 1st picture into new table ML2 with 2 columns as in 2nd picture?

Comment: Its a one time job??

Comment: I think NO! This is just part of column! All table has 128 rows!

Comment: Really? You're going to write a program to update 128 rows in a database? Use a text editor to amend a CSV extract or use a spreadheet to generate individual states like `UPDATE yourtable SET coil1='Toronto', col2='Praptors' WHERE col1='Toronto Raptors'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your second column does not include any spaces, we can search for the location of the last space, and then split there:

```
SELECT Klubs, 
substr(Klubs, 1, char_length(Klubs) - instr(reverse(Klubs),' ')) as Region, 
substr(Klubs,  char_length(Klubs) - instr(reverse(Klubs),' ')+2) as Club
FROM ML;
```

I search for the the space with [`instr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr), and to do this reverse I use the [`reverse`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) function on the string first, and then to compensate I subtract it from the length of the string with [`char_length`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).

You could insert it in a [new table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) (ML2):

```
create table ML2
<the query>
```

or [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html):

```
create view ML2 as
<the query>
```

Comment: **Thanks!** Worked for all table!